# Communicating with ActionCable from different host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I have an api server on one host (say, host1) and a rails5 application on another (host2). Host1 app is written in python, if it matters.
Host1 processes incoming events and should send the result in a json object to the rails application. Rails should receive this object and process further.

What is the correct syntax/protocol/way of sending data from host1 to action_cable on host2 so that the data is `streamed_from` that channel? I'm okay with setting up cables etc, but I cannot figure out how and where should host1 send its messages.

I have almost decided to POST json to rails but this does not seem to be the `true` way as the data is updated frequently and a websocket seems to be the best solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with python but in order for websocket to work you have to keep a WS connection open somehow from host1 to host2. You might need another system such as kafka for what you are trying to do

Comment: I have set up a test server to receive messages via WS and it works well: host1 keeps connection and sends the payload.

I mean to ask how to send them to action_cable in the proper way. There should be some format like {"type": "message", "identifier": '...", data: '...'} as it is being sent inside application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as expected, that was pretty easy and straightforward once you know the answer.

[This article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/talking-to-actioncable-without-rails) is the main source of my inspiration and it makes everything much clearer than the action_cable guides.

In short, I had to ensure that the connection is `identified_by` and that there's a method responsible for the data processing.
The main caveat was although in `stringify`ing the messages sent to host1. You just have to be careful here and double check all the quotes/slashes.